# Visual Studio 2013 web project properties window not showing all the properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2013

An ASP.NET MVC 5 project on my Windows 7 does not show all the properties of the project when I change the Web server from IIS Express to Local IIS. For example:

**When web server is IIS Express** (default when you create a web project):

[image]

**When web server is changed to Local IIS**: I would like to set the SSL URL or other properties through this window but there is only one property available there.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local IIS runs independently of visual studio. Thus there are no config options in VS.
You need to configure the local (true) IIS within its own config MMC or powerscript like a remote server or you need to consider this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(v=vs.120).aspx#iisdisadvantages

Comment: You may have misunderstood my question. I can do that configuration in IIS. **Question** is why the project window shown in the red rectangle in figure 2 of my post not showing all the properties that the same window in figure is showing?

Comment: I understood well. but local IIS runs independently of visual studio. thus no config options unless https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(v=vs.120).aspx#iisdisadvantages

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Could you please add your comments to your response and I'll mark it as an answer.